# Multiple Python versions on the same machine?

Tags: python

Is there official documentation on the Python website somewhere, on how to install and run multiple versions of Python on the same machine on Linux?

I can find gazillions of blog posts and answers, but I want to know if there is a "standard" official way of doing this?

Or is this all dependent on OS?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I think it is totally independent. Just install them, then you have the commands e.g. `/usr/bin/python2.5` and `/usr/bin/python2.6`. Link `/usr/bin/python` to the one you want to use as default.

All the libraries are in separate folders (named after the version) anyway.

If you want to compile the versions manually, this is from the readme file of the Python source code:

> Installing multiple versions

> On Unix and Mac systems if you intend to install multiple versions of Python
> using the same installation prefix (`--prefix` argument to the configure
> script) you must take care that your primary python executable is not
> overwritten by the installation of a different version.  All files and
> directories installed using `make altinstall` contain the major and minor
> version and can thus live side-by-side.  `make install` also creates
> `${prefix}/bin/python3` which refers to `${prefix}/bin/pythonX.Y`.  If you intend
> to install multiple versions using the same prefix you must decide which
> version (if any) is your "primary" version.  Install that version using
> `make install`.  Install all other versions using `make altinstall`.

> For example, if you want to install Python 2.5, 2.6 and 3.0 with 2.6 being
> the primary version, you would execute `make install` in your 2.6 build
> directory and `make altinstall` in the others.

Comment: Thanks, the "make install" on primary and "make altinstall" on secondary made it clear.

Comment: Any correct way to share libraries between versions? Let's say I have MySQLdb for 2.6, then installed 2.7. how do I make MySQLdb available for 2.7 too?

Comment: All the information you give is for Unix/Linux and Mac OS, so clearly not "totally independent" of OS, as the OP asks. For Windows the process is quite different but equally easy.

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks! So you are saying I could install python3.6, 3.7 (one with install other with altinstall) then I could work with both? I'm kind of unsure as to how to link to 3.6 and 3.7? Also what if we want more than 2 versions?

Comment: @haneulkim: This is a very old answer. I haven't worked with Python in a long while. Maybe these days something like https://asdf-vm.com/ is more useful.

Comment: @FelixKling "Link /usr/bin/python to the one you want to use as default." may I kindly ask you to show how to do it?

Answer (score 37):

### Update 2019: Using `asdf`

These days I suggest using [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) to install various versions of Python interpreters next to each other.

*Note1: `asdf` works not only for Python but for all major languages.*

*Note2: `asdf` works fine in combination with popular package-managers such as [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/) and [poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/).*

If you have [asdf installed](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf-vm?id=install-asdf-vm) you can easily download/install new Python interpreters:

```
# Install Python plugin for asdf:
asdf plugin-add python

# List all available Python interpreters:
asdf list-all python

# Install the Python interpreters that you need:
asdf install python 3.7.4
asdf install python 3.6.9
# etc...

# If you want to define the global version:
asdf global python 3.7.4

# If you want to define the local (project) version:
# (this creates a file .tool-versions in the current directory.)
asdf local python 3.7.4
```

### Old Answer: Install Python from source

If you need to install multiple versions of Python (next to the main one) on a Unix system:

1. Install Required Packages for source compilation

   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
   $ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
2. Download and extract desired Python version

[Download Python Source for Linux](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) as tarball and move it to `/usr/src`.

Extract the downloaded package in place. *(replace the 'x's with your downloaded version)*

```
$ sudo tar xzf Python-x.x.x.tgz
```

3. Compile and Install Python Source

   $ cd Python-x.x.x
   $ sudo ./configure
   $ sudo make altinstall

Your new Python bin is now located in `/usr/local/bin`. You can test the new version:

```
$ pythonX.X -V
Python x.x.x
$ which pythonX.X
/usr/local/bin/pythonX.X

# Pip is now available for this version as well:
$ pipX.X -V
pip X.X.X from /usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages (python X.X)
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug using asdf with poetry: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3890.

Answer (score 32):

On Windows they get installed to separate folders, "C:\python26" and "C:\python31", but the executables have the same "python.exe" name.

I created another "C:\python" folder that contains "python.bat" and "python3.bat" that serve as wrappers to "python26" and "python31" respectively, and added "C:\python" to the `PATH` environment variable.

This allows me to type `python` or `python3` in my .bat Python wrappers to start the one I desire.

On Linux, you can use the `#!` trick to specify which version you want a script to use.

Comment: What to add into those .bat files?

Comment: Won't upvote this answer only because it's very windows-specific and the question was Linux related, otherwise great info.

Comment: User no longer exists, I really wanted that batch file

Comment: This is what I put in my python.bat file (just one line): 

"c:\python27\python %*"

Then I just invoke it normally, i.e. 'python test.py' and the %* will grab all the arguments and pass it to the actual executable. You can also use mklink directly in your C:\bin folder. See here for the details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13953614/865929

Comment: Now you can just run `py -3.4` or `py -2.7` and the program `py` (under `C:\Windows`) will choose that python interpreter (assuming it's installed).

Answer (score 20):

#### I'm using Mac & the best way that worked for me is using pyenv!

The commands below are for Mac but pretty similar to Linux (see the links below)

```
#Install pyenv
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

Let's say you have python 3.7.6 as your primary version on your mac:

```
python --version
```

Output:

```
Python 3.7.6
```

#### Now Install python 3.10

Fist, we can check if it's already there, run:

```
pyenv install --list
```

Scroll up (right above anacoda) to check if it's there/installed, if not, run:

```
pyenv install 3.10
```

Make sure to run this in the Terminal (add it to ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc):

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Now let's run it only on the opened [terminal/shell](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-shell):

```
pyenv shell 3.10
```

#### Now run

```
python --version
```

Output:

```
Python 3.10.9
```

And not less important **unset** it in the opened shell/iTerm:

```
pyenv shell --unset
```

You can run it [globally](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-global) or [locally](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local) as well

Answer (score 11):

## Package Managers - user-level

For a package manager that can install and manage multiple versions of python, these are good choices:

- [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) - only able to install and manage versions of python
- [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) - able to install and manage many different languages

The advantages to these package managers is that it may be easier to set them up and install multiple versions of python with them than it is to install python from source. They also provide commands for easily changing the available python version(s) using shims and setting the python version per-directory.

This disadvantage is that, by default, they are installed at the user-level (inside your home directory) and require a little bit of user-level configuration - you'll need to edit your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` or similar files. This means that it is not easy to use them to install multiple python versions globally for all users. In order to do this, you can install from source alongside the OS's existing python version.

---

## Installation from source - system-wide

You'll need root privileges for this method.

See the [official python documentation for building from source](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python) for additional considerations and options.

`/usr/local` is the designated location for a system administrator to install shared (system-wide) software, so it's subdirectories are a good place to download the python source and install. See [section 4.9 of the Linux Foundation's File Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#usrlocalLocalHierarchy).

Install any build dependencies. On Debian-based systems, use:

```
apt update
apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libbz2-dev
```

Choose which python version you want to install. See the [Python Source Releases](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/Python-3.7.7.tgz) page for a listing.

Download and unzip file in `/usr/local/src`, replacing `X.X.X` below with the python version (i.e. `3.8.2`).

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/X.X.X/Python-X.X.X.tgz
tar vzxf Python-X.X.X.tgz
```

Before building and installing, set the `CFLAGS` environment variable with C compiler flags necessary (see GNU's [`make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-CFLAGS)). This is usually not necessary for general use, but if, for example, you were going to create a uWSGI plugin with this python version, you might want to set the flags, `-fPIC`, with the following:

```
export CFLAGS='-fPIC'
```

Change the working directory to the unzipped python source directory, and configure the build. You'll probably want to use the `--enable-optimizations` option on the `./configure` command for [profile guided optimization](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/README.rst#profile-guided-optimization). Use `--prefix=/usr/local` to install to the proper subdirectories (`/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc.).

```
cd Python-X.X.X
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local
```

Build the project with `make` and install with `make altinstall` to avoid overriding any files when installing multiple versions. See the warning on [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python) of the python build documentation.

```
make -j 4
make altinstall
```

Then you should be able to run your new python and pip versions with `pythonX.X` and `pipX.X` (i.e `python3.8` and `pip3.8`). Note that if the minor version of your new installation is the same as the OS's version (for example if you were installing python3.8.4 and the OS used python3.8.2), then you would need to specify the entire path (`/usr/local/bin/pythonX.X`) or set an alias to use this version.

Answer (score 6):

How to install different Python versions is indeed OS dependent.

However, if you're on linux, you can use a tool like [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) or [pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) to help you easily manage and switch between different versions.

Comment: I've installed on a mac with configure/make altinstall. No problems so far.

Comment: Is it possible to give `$user1` another python version than default?

Comment: @Roland `pyenv` will work for that. From the readme in the link posted above:
> [Lets] you change the global Python version on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 4):

### Fedora Linux - simply install from packages

Probably worth noting that Fedora distro includes older versions of Python that are not EOL'ed. I find it quite convenient.

For example in the recent Fedora 35 (autumn 2021), the default Python is 3.10, but you can install 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9 as well.

The packages are described as:

> Python 3.X package for developers.
>
> This package exists to allow developers to test their code against an older
> version of Python. This is not a full Python stack and if you wish to run
> your applications with Python 3., see other distributions
> that support it, such as an older Fedora release.

To install for instance the 3.7 as an addition to the installed Python *(shell command line, as root or with `sudo`)*:

```
dnf install python3.7
```

There is no `pip`, one must start with (*shell command line, regular user*):

```
python3.7 -m ensurepip --user --altinstall
# --altinstall will create pip3.7 but will not overwrite pip3
```

and then we can normally continue:

```
pip3.7 install --user pytest ... # or whatever you need
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most strongly dependent on the package distribution system you use.  For example, with MacPorts, you can install multiple Python packages and use the `pyselect` utility to switch the default between them with ease. At all times, you're able to call the different Python interpreters by providing the full path, and you're able to link against all the Python libraries and headers by providing the full paths for those.

So basically, whatever way you install the versions, as long as you keep your installations separate, you'll able to run them separately.

Comment: What is a package distribution system?

Comment: @drozzy: For example RPM used by OpenSuse or apt used by Debian-based distributions or portage used by Gentoo etc. Basically it is a tool to install software.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with anaconda navigator. I installed anaconda navigator and created two different development environments with different python versions

and switch between different python versions by switching or activating and deactivating environments.

first install anaconda navigator and then create environments.

see help here on how to manage environments

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/manage-environments/

Here is the video to do it with conda

https://youtu.be/EGaw6VXV3GI

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to throw in another way to do this, which is to install additional versions of Python alongside the system default.  It's lightweight if all you need is just one other version of Python for some specific project. It's using the deadsnakes PPA, so this is specific to Ubuntu Linux.

Instructions. Add the PPA

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Now suppose you want Python 3.5:

```sh
sudo apt install python3.5 python3.5-dev python3.5-venv
```

You can then use the `python3.5` executable in your path, if you want.

Now if you need to create a venv for a specific project,

```sh
cd your-project
python3.5 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Side note - I did try the popular 'pyenv', but found that it was doing too much in the bashrc/profile, and was slowing down shell prompt.  Also, installations of new Python versions were very slow as it was compiling each version.  pyenv is probably better if you need to switch between Python versions a lot for many projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [**pyenv**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). It is a python version manager that can help you manage multiple versions of python on the same machine.