# How programmatically run another python script with other python version?

Tags: python

If I write program in python 2.7 and I want to run another script file with another python (2.6) how can I do this?

EDIT: I do this, because I need Django (which is installed in python 2.7) and I need some programs that are only available for python 2.6...

EDIT2: So I wrote simple script, that will be executed in python 2.6 and I will get results from it right in python 2.7

Comment: May i refer to you to the following question with the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/official-multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine Your question is asked there. :)

Comment: There are several ways to call external process in python. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python) question for details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options, but the most general concept is to use `os.system` to do your script execution.

#### Explicit interpreter

```
os.system('python2.6 myscript.py')
```

#### Relying on shebang for choosing the right interpreter

```
os.system('myscript.py')
```

For this to work your script has to have the first line set to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

And your `python2.6` executable needs to be in your `PATH`.

#### If you need stdin/stdout manipulation

```
subprocess.Popen('myscript.py', subprocess.PIPE) #relying on shebang
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'python2.6', 'myscript.py'], subprocess.PIPE) #manual interpreter selection
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen