# How to specify python version used to create Virtual Environment through venv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, development-environment, python-venv

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45293436/2989289), [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#section-discovery) has `-p` and `--python` flags that allow user to define python interpreter desired version to be used in the *to-be-created* virtual environment

Reading up [venv official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments), I haven't found such an option described. So I'm look for an alternative to achieve same behavior. Some guess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use different Python version in venv from standard library? (Not virtualenv!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22681824/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running: `py -3.8 -m venv virtualenv`. This is the method I’ve been using which does create a virtual environment in the corresponding Python version. There may be other methods, however. Naturally, replace py3.8 with whoever version you want to use.