# Can't install Matplotlib on Python 3.10 after its release (2021-10-05)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, module, pip, python-3.10

After the release of Python 3.10, I reinstalled my modules for the newest version and I'm getting some trouble. First of all I tried to pip Numpy as it's the required one for matplotlib. But I got this problem:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Even though unsuccessful, I tried to install Matplotlib.

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6mmzj8ln\\matplotlib_e4d8611ecbaa485193e456f5c8639d79\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6mmzj8ln\\matplotlib_e4d8611ecbaa485193e456f5c8639d79\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-x6onvveu'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6mmzj8ln\matplotlib_e4d8611ecbaa485193e456f5c8639d79\
    Complete output (257 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpywamgc6e'
           cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rd1a5_s\numpy_0a0aa0c0c565418fa8227e992c062b49
      Complete output (208 lines):
      setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
        warnings.warn(
      Running from numpy source directory.
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rd1a5_s\numpy_0a0aa0c0c565418fa8227e992c062b49\tools\cythonize.py:69: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
        from distutils.version import LooseVersion
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rd1a5_s\numpy_0a0aa0c0c565418fa8227e992c062b49\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rd1a5_s\numpy_0a0aa0c0c565418fa8227e992c062b49\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rd1a5_s\numpy_0a0aa0c0c565418fa8227e992c062b49\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
        NOT AVAILABLE

      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rd1a5_s\numpy_0a0aa0c0c565418fa8227e992c062b49\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rd1a5_s\numpy_0a0aa0c0c565418fa8227e992c062b49\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
        FOUND:
          language = c
          define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

      Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 75, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpsew9x6oz', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.16']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6mmzj8ln\matplotlib_e4d8611ecbaa485193e456f5c8639d79\setup.py", line 258, in <module>
        setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 785, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1051, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1063, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 844, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 77, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpsew9x6oz', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.16']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.4.2]
          python: yes [3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC
                      v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/d3/286925802edaeb0b8834425ad97c9564ff679eb4208a184533969aa5fc29/matplotlib-3.4.2.tar.gz#sha256=d8d994cefdff9aaba45166eb3de4f5211adb4accac85cbf97137e98f26ea0219 (from https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also tried to install from source like this and got the same error:

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
python -m pip install -e .
```

Have I made some mistake?

Comment: matplotlib requires pyqt which requires python <= 3.9: `matplotlib -> pyqt -> python[version='2.7.*|3.6.*|>=3.6|>=3|<3|3.8.*|3.7.*|3.9.*']` and `matplotlib -> python[version='3.4.*|3.5.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']`

Comment: Python 3.10 released very recently.  Don't expect all the libraries to be ported to it yet.  Don't switch to 3.10 until the libraries you need to use support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated, Python 3.10 is not currently compatible with Matplotlib.
You need to install and use Python 3.9 until it is supported. Until then you have a few options:

### Windows

You can use the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) (py.exe) script to choose which Python version to run like so:

py.exe script help:
`py -h`

List all installed versions
`py -0`

Use a specified version
`py -3.9`

*e.g. 1*
Create a virtual environment using python 3.9
`py -3.9 venv .venv`

*e.g. 2*
install matplotlib with pip using python 3.9
`py -3.9 -m pip install matplotlib`

### Linux

On Linux you can run whatever Python version you like like so:

`python3.9`

You can set up a local (your working directory and all sub-directories) virtual environment that will use your specified version like so:

`python3.9 -m venv .venv`

Which will set the version of python used to 3.9 while in the local directory, and allow you to type `python` instead of `python3.9` each time you need it.

Another relevant and helpful post by [Rotareti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612318/rotareti) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40453839/13618936).

Please note that I have not described how to activate and use Python Virtual Environments here in detail, for more information on using them read the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments).

Reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69791909/7758804) if you're interested in installing a matplotlib release candidate.

Answer (score -1):

`python -m pip install -ve`

And a few extra characters just so it will go through.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).