# Error trying to install matplotlib in Windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pip, qhull

I'm trying to install matplotlib for Python 3.10 in Windows. Im using pip: `pip install matplotlib` I've already installed NumPy, Cython, Pillow and other libraries needed. But it shows this error:

```
error: Failed to download any of the following: ['http://www.qhull.org/download/qhull-2020-src-8.0.2.tgz'].  Please download one of these urls and extract it into 'build/' at the top-level of the source repository.
```

I've downloaded the said library and copied it in   `.cache/matplotlib/build` but it doesnt work.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you installing these modules? Which commands did you run?

Comment: pip install matplotlib Edit: added it to the question as I didnt mention it before

Comment: I see. Never encountered this issue. Is this the whole error output?

Comment: Please try `pip install --pre matplotlib`. The latest stable release does not support python 3.10 yet (I hope you didn't actually mean python 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

So as @FlyingTeller commented, there are no stable realeses of matplotlib so using `--pre` fixed the problem.