# Matplotlib not running in vscode even after the other packages are installed and working

Tags: python, matplotlib

All other packedges like numpy, pygame etc runs, but the matplotlib libraning is showing this error repeatedly. I've done multiple times restallation and tries to solve this issue with AI help. but just couldn't. Any kind people out there knows the root of the problem! and the solution please help. thanks, Teresa

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "h:\simu\pure.py", line 3, in <module>
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
        _check_versions()
      File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 266, in _check_versions
        module = importlib.import_module(modname)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from ._cext import (
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
    
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Does this help: [matplotlib-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-cext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824703/matplotlib-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-cext)

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried it earlier. Didn't work

Comment: The python version is 3.12.1 and matplotlib version is 3.8.2

Comment: What did you try? There are at least two suggestions in that post.

Comment: pip install msvc-runtime command at first it didn't work. Later suggested for installing a c/c++ distribution. installed, restarted and re entered the command. still not working

Comment: I've just install this pip install setuptools_scm  and now one more error remaining, "Cannot create consistent method ordering" in the __init__.py of /C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py

Comment: Seems other have had similar issues: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18292/ To be honest it sounds like an issue could be opened up with matplotlib (as you so was done in the above case). You may want to try downgrading to a version that's been in use for a longer period of time (for matplotlib, maybe for python as well).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69791909/9384858 this one did the work, thanks StackOverflow community