# How do I Upgrade Python in Virtual Environment

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, python-venv

I have Python `3.10.9` globally, however version `3.9.15` is still showing up in the virtual environment.
How do I upgrade Python in my virtual enviroment?

Previously Anaconda was in the root path, and after many frustrating attempts I finally got rid of conda and miniconda3 in the path.  Could this somehow be related to this issue?[image: Terminal Screen Shot]

Attempted to upgrade Python via Homebrew - which told me that version `3.10.9` is already installed, it's just not linked.  I proceeded through the steps and attempted to link `python@3.10` - however this failed, as version `3.9.15` is *still* showing.[image: Terminal using Homebrew]

Comment: Virtual environments are not designed to work that way. Instead, **create a new one** based off the new desired Python version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use different Python version in venv from standard library? (Not virtualenv!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681824/how-do-i-use-different-python-version-in-venv-from-standard-library-not-virtua)

Comment: Are you using pipenv?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Creating a new one solved the issue, thank you.  To be clear, so there is no way to upgrade a python version in an existing virtual environment?

Comment: Running `python3 -m venv --upgrade  .venv` had no effect when I checked the version

Comment: That would be for upgrading the version *of venv*, not of Python.