# Upgrading from Python 2.7 to 3.6 - Completely uninstall 2.7 or run side by side?

Tags: python

I have only been using Python seriously at work for the previous year (2.7), so I apologise if this is a stupid question.

I want to upgrade to 3.6.

Do I completely uninstall Python from my computer and then start again with 3.6, or can you install 3.6 in parallels with 2.7?

I rather completely reinstall and start again, are there any problems with doing that?

This is different from: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/official-multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine` As I want to know if there are any problems with uninstalling Python 2.7 first./

Many thanks!

Comment: Your system most likely needs the older version of Python, so do not uninstall it.

Comment: Your OS is probably relying on your Python 2.7 installation, I'd not uninstall it. That's certainly the case for OS X and many Linux distributions.

Comment: You can have both side by side. In fact, removing Python 2.x on Mac OSX [is not recommended](https://superuser.com/questions/528265/is-it-safe-to-uninstall-python-2-from-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion).

Comment: I am sorry, I should have said I am using Windows. What do you mean by 'relying'? and thank you.

Comment: Relying == lots of software on OS X and Linux use Python to run in, removing Python on those platforms will break the OS. Windows doesn't so it is safe to remove Python 2.7 there.

Comment: Great, thank you Martijn. I understand