# how do I remove other python versions and keep on just python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed Python3.5.6 but when I check my terminal I found that I have also Python 2.7.15rc1 and Python 3.6.7
When I type Python, I leads to Python 2.7.15rc1
When I type Python3, I leads to Python 3.5.6
When I type Python3.5, I leads to Python 3.5.6
When I type Python3.6, I leads to Python 3.6.7

Please help because I can't install packages like numpy using pip3 on Python 3.5

I want to keep on just Python 3.5

Comment: When you install from source you should do make alt-install to allow proper versions to stay separate from each other, so you can maintain major version numbers like 3.5 3.6, 2.7 is the default on lots of linux distros and you don't want to overwrite that binary to avoid breaking lots of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a virtual environment

```
$ python3.x -m venv <venvname>
linux   $ source venvname/bin/activate
windows > source venvname/bin/activate.ps1
```

the virtual environment in your terminal to install to that local separate copy.

or reinstall with "make altinstall" -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547577/6529424