# Is it possible to have both Python3.6 and Python3.8 versions installed at same time in windows machine

Tags: python

I am going through a Django tutorial but it's an old one. The videos were all made using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6. Problem is I have installed python3.8 in my machine. So I was trying to create virtualenv with python version 3.6. But as python 3.6 is not available in my machine, I couldn't do that. At this point I was wondering even if it is actually possible to have both python 3.6 and python 3.8 in a machine at same time.

Kindly someone help me with this problem or point me to the right resource to understand more on this problem.

Comment: That's probably better than my initial link: https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097

Comment: You should not have a problem because of 3.8 to 3.6 alone. But I still recommend that you figure out how to have several versions side by side and use a virtualenv, specially when dealing with django.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run multiple Python versions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows) … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have two versions of python installed on the same machine. You might have to do some path manipulation to get things working, depending on the specifics of your setup. You can also probably just follow along with the tutorial using python 3.8 even if the tutorial it-self uses 3.6.

You can also use the python launcher to manage multiple versions of python installed on the same machine: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Comment: Yes, also worth mentioning the "Python launcher": https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks Tantalum, I installed python 3.6 and finally able to create virtual environment with version 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can have both versions installed on single machine. All u need to do is to download Python3.6 from its Official site, set your Interpreter to python3.6 and u r all set.