# Opening Python code with a specific version

Tags: python

while there are multiple versions of Python installed on a Linux machine, is there a way to mention in the script to be open with a specific version, say, 3.8 even if we issue the #python script.py as opposed to python3.8 script.py ?
I don't want to use Linux alias command. I wanna know if that is possible to be accomplished within the script

Comment: You could write your own wrapper (e.g. a shell script) that takes a version option and then dispatches to the specified Python version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Python versions on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the interpreter by adding
`#!/usr/bin/env pythonXX`
as the first line in your script, provided the version is in the path.
You can also invoke the interpreter directly with the script as the argument.

`pythonXX script.py`

Depending on your situation

`pythonXX -E script.py`

might be better. That way the interpreter ignores paths set by environmental variables. 
For more details view
https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 1):

Use shebang. `#!/usr/bin/python`
In the first line of the code with the serial number of Python you want at the end.

You'll need to then run your script like ./my_script.py