# Uninstalling Python3.8 , will i loose my all installed packages?

Tags: python

I was using python 3.8 but when I started writing code on face recognition it requires python of 64 bit..
so suggest me either I should uninstall the 32bit python and install 64bit python..(would i loose my installed packages like kivy,pandas,tkinter..etc.) or I can run 64bit and 32bit on my machine simultaneously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Python versions on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine)

Comment: You can use pip subcommand "freeze"  to get a list and version of all installed packages.  this list may be put in a file and used as part of a specification to pip of packages to install.  so save the data, uninstall and reinstall the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

So, unfortunately all your python packages will be lost if you uninstall python because they are kept in the same folder:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

You might be able to specifically save this folder, then copy it back into your new installation of python, but don't take my word for it!