# I've installed python-3.9.1 and pip but while running the command python3 -V got the result as python 3.6.9 how do I get python version 3.9

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.7, python-install

sudo apt-get install python3.7

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

python3.7 is already the newest version (3.7.10-1+bionic2).

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

N: Ignoring file 'security' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
root@ubuntu:~# python3 -V
Python 3.6.9

Comment: Please share more details - how should anybody know how to help if you dump only some output from your console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run multiple Python versions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows)

Comment: And for Linux: [Multiple Python versions on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2547554/6045800)

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are a Linux user. I faced a similar issue when I was trying to install Python
3.9 but when I ran python -V in the terminal, it would tell me I had version 2.
I can't guarantee

this will work but it worked for me. If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 a Linux distro, by default you have Python 3.9. In Ubuntu 18 and 16 there is also a Python version pre-installed. In your case, you need to first uninstall Python 3.
Using this command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3
```

After uninstalling, reinstall as Python 3.9 version using this command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9
python3.9 --version
```

Again if you're using an editor like Pycharm **your base interpreter will be messed up! So please be careful when uninstalling.**
And this code works on Ubuntu which I presume is what you are working on.
Another thing you need to install a repository to get Py 3.9. it's called deadsnakes I've mentioned the code above on how you could install it.
I hope you faced no issues. Remember it worked for me but I'm not sure it will work for you. Enjoy with Python 3.9 if the installation is successful :)

Comment: Do upvote and accept my answer if you found it useful

Comment: You can help me a lot by doing so.

Comment: yea but you're still using `python3.9` instead of `python3` / `python` so the default version is still wrong